# OmniAuth on Heroku with custom domain results in Application Error

Tags: ruby, heroku, openid, omniauth

I have an application on Heroku which uses omniauth and authenticates correctly when I visit `myapplication.heroku.com/auth/open_id`, input my google endpoint, and get redirected back.

However, when I visit `myapplication.com`, with heroku custom domains setup and working for every other url, I get `Application Error` from heroku after being redirected back from Google (I have not tried other openid providers).

I have hoptoad setup and it is not sending me any notifications about the specific error (probably because omniauth is middleware). Nothing shows up in `heroku logs` besides that there was a `[nginx] GET` request at the url which gave the error.

it probably doesn't matter, but this is a rails app.

localhost production testing works fine.

ideas?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem after enabling a custom domain.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this fixes your problem, but I encountered a similar problem on my app (OAuth with Facebook, Rails, Heroku). It turned out the problem was caused by the following line:

```
session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
```

(which stores the OAuth data in the session in case the user does not have an account yet and has to complete a signup form before he can be persisted).

This caused a `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow` (which also [was not reported by Hoptoad/Airbrake](http://help.airbrake.io/discussions/problems/1558-cookieoverflow-not-being-reported)) for some users whose `omniauth.auth` hash was too large to be stored in the session cookie. Hence I fixed this issue by preprocessing the hash and throwing out everything that is not needed, before saving it to session. Maybe your bug is related to this?

Comment: Oh god! ```env["omniauth.auth"]``` contains ALL the basic info! Friends, work info Likes, etc. Yes, that will probably overflow the 4Kb

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

myurl.com resulted in 502 bad gateway, while .herokuapp.com worked fine.

I had set

`use Rack::Session::Cookie`

To enable session cookies, but for some reason, the Ngnix proxy at Heroku didn't like this. When i changed it to:

`use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
:path => '/',
:expire_after => 14400,
:secret => 'change_me'`

ie. made sure there was no domain key in the hash.

Comment: Actually i think that you need to remove the domain from the Cookie options. This works for me:
`use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
:path => '/',
:expire_after => 14400,
:secret => 'change_me'`